# Microsoft Visual Studio XNA 4.0 Not Supported Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I Downloaded Microsoft XNA 4.0 And I'm Getting An Error How Can I Fix It
Error:
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Your installation of XNA Game Studio does not support this project (XNA Platform = 'Windows', XNA Framework Version = 'v4.0').  Deneme"

I am using visual studio 2017

(And my english is a bit bad so i use translation please ignore if i have mistakes thanks in advance)

Comment: Have you tried [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft+XNA+4.0+vs+2017) it?

Comment: Task manager in processes and find your project name, then right click and end process. Then open your project in Visual Studio, click Run

Comment: didn't work, is there any other method?